# I am unable to query pricebook entry. (Internal Salesforce Error)

Tags: apex, query, pricebookentry

I am making a lightning component for a user to create a quote + line items quick and easy. However the apex function that is meant to query the pricebook entry and its Id for each line item is causing an internal salesforce error.

I am unsure as to why, because another function has pretty much the same query and works fine.

Here is the function currently breaking:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String createQuoteAndLineItems(Quote newQuote, List<QuoteLineItem> newQuoteItems)
{
    try
    {
        //insert newQuote;
        for(QuoteLineItem currentItem : newQuoteItems)
        {
            currentItem.QuoteId = newQuote.Id;
            system.debug(currentItem);
            system.debug(currentItem.UnitPrice);
            system.debug(currentItem.Collection_Frequency__c);
            system.debug(currentItem.QuoteId);
            system.debug(currentItem.Product2Id);
        }
        //insert newQuoteItems;
        return 'Success';
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        system.debug(e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getStackTraceString());
        return e.getMessage() + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString();
    }
}
```

Internal error caused when trying to debug or query using Product2Id.

Update: Turns out I needed to do "Product2Id.Id" instead of just "Product2Id"... lol

Comment: can your print and see size of newQuoteItems ?

Comment: Yeah, I can see them in my debug. However something new i've discovered is when I try to just debug the product2Id, it also gives an internal error. But the list I debug shows the product2Id just fine

Comment: You are doing SOQL in for-loop hich will cause Limits Exception which cannot be caught by the catch block and you are getting Internal Salesforce Errr.

Comment: Ah alright. I normally avoid soql in for loops, but I couldn't figure a way around this one. At most 10 queries are done so I thought it'd be alright, guess not ahah

Comment: Hi, so I've removed any queries done, and just have debugs. If I try to debug any specific field on the quotelineitem from the list i've passed in, I get an internal error. Debugging the whole item works fine though?

Comment: can you update the code snippet?

Comment: Updated it. Line 62 debugs fine, then right after where it is debugging the product2Id I get an internal error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94710/discussion-between-pranay-jaiswal-and-alexander-atkinsoon).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it's breaking. The custom lookup I was using for Product2Id had Product2Id as an object holding the name and the Id of the selected record.

So I just needed to pass in only the Id in my JS controller with Product2Id.Id.